# Get initials and full last name from a string containing names

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

Assume there are some strings containing names in different format (each line is a possible user input):

```
'Guilcher, G.M., Harvey, M. & Hand, J.P.'
'Ri Liesner, Peter Tom Collins, Michael Richards'
'Manco-Johnson M, Santagostino E, Ljung R.'
```

I need to transform those names to get the format `Lastname ABC`. So each surename should be transformed to its initial which are appended to the lastname.

The example should result in

```
Guilcher GM, Harvey M, Hand JP
Liesner R, Collins PT, Richards M
Manco-Johnson M, Santagostino E, Ljung R
```

The problem is the different (possible) input format. I think my attempts are not very smart, so I'm asking for

1. Some hints to optimize the transformation code
2. How do I put those in a single function at all? I think first of all I have to test which format the string has...??

So let me explain how far I tried to solve that:

**First example string**

In the first example there are initials followed by a dot. The dots should be removed and the comma between the name and the initals should be removed.

```
firstString
  .replace('.', '')
  .replace(' &', ', ')
```

I think I do need an regex to get the comma after the name and before the initials.

**Second example string**

In the second example the name should be splitted by space and the last element is handled as lastname:

```
const elm = secondString.split(/\s+/)
const lastname = elm[elm.length - 1]
const initials = elm.map((n,i) => {
  if (i !== elm.length - 1) return capitalizeFirstLetter(n)
})

return lastname + ' ' + initals.join('')
```

...not very elegant

**Third example string**

The third example has the already the correct format - only the dot at the end has to be removed. So nothing else has to be done with that input.

Comment: Given your strings, you need to properly find a delimiter to split on names.  Normally I would say comma, but the comma is used a separation between lastname and titles.  Do you have control over this list of names, and the delimiters they create?

Comment: is each string one name only? I would assume 'Guilcher, G.M.' is one string, and 'Harvey, M. & Hand, J.P.' is another string.

Is every name beside the one with an & connecting them a single name per string? Or am I misunderstanding, and this is actually one string of multiple names?

Comment: @DevinFields it is always one string of multiple names. Each line is one string and one possible user input

Comment: @Fallenreaper no, i dont have control over that

Comment: Well, you'll first have to devise a way of separating the names. My first thought is to check the contents after each comma. Upon hitting the first comma, check if the following contents contains a period. If it does, you can include that in the contents prior to than comma. If not it is most likely the beginning of a new name. Account for edge cases, such the & joining two name and that instance of 'Harvey, M. & Hand, J.P. Ri Liesner' (unless there was supposed to be a comma after the J.P.)

Comment: These look like lists of authors in typical journal article citations (which I've dealt with), making the form `{name}, {name}, ... [,&] {name}` and where `{name}` can be in one of the several forms in your examples. I would approach it as grammar productions, which regexes can help parse, but it's not a simple matter of regex-replace. Maybe with lookaheads/lookbehinds you could manage it, but you would have write-only code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't be possible without calling multiple `replace()` methods. The steps in provided solution is as following:

- Remove all dots in abbreviated names
- Substitute lastname with firstname
- Replace lastnames with their beginning letter
- Remove unwanted characters

Demo:

```js
var s = `Guilcher, G.M., Harvey, M. & Hand, J.P.
Ri Liesner, Peter Tom Collins, Michael Richards
Manco-Johnson M, Santagostino E, Ljung R.`

// Remove all dots in abbreviated names
var b = s.replace(/\b([A-Z])\./g, '$1')
// Substitute first names and lastnames
.replace(/([A-Z][\w-]+(?: +[A-Z][\w-]+)*) +([A-Z][\w-]+)\b/g, ($0, $1, $2) => {
    // Replace full lastnames with their first letter
    return $2 + " " + $1.replace(/\b([A-Z])\w+ */g, '$1');
})
// Remove unwanted preceding / following commas and ampersands 
.replace(/(,) +([A-Z]+)\b *[,&]?/g, ' $2$1');

console.log(b);
```

Comment: The first line of the result has an unneeded comma at the end: `Hand JP,` Could you fix that?

Comment: The easiest way would be to chain it with `.replace(/,\s*$/m, '')`. The longest way would be changing last `replace` into `replace(/(?:(,) +([A-Z]+)\b *[,&]?(?!\s*$)|, +([A-Z]+)\b *[,&]?)/gm, ' $2$3$1');`

Answer (score 1):

Given your example data i would try to make guesses based on name part count = 2, since it is very hard to rely on any `,`, `&` or `\n` - which means treat them all as `,`.

Try this against your data and let me know of any use-cases where this fails because i am highly confident that this script will fail at some point with more data :)

```js
let testString = "Guilcher, G.M., Harvey, M. & Hand, J.P.\nRi Liesner, Peter Tom Collins, Michael Richards\nManco-Johnson M, Santagostino E, Ljung R.";

const inputToArray = i => i
    .replace(/\./g, "")
    .replace(/[\n&]/g, ",")
    .replace(/ ?, ?/g, ",")
    .split(',');

const reducer = function(accumulator, value, index, array) {
    let pos = accumulator.length - 1;
    let names = value.split(' ');
    if(names.length > 1) {
        accumulator.push(names);
    } else {
        if(accumulator[pos].length > 1) accumulator[++pos] = [];
        accumulator[pos].push(value);
    }
    return accumulator.filter(n => n.length > 0);
};

console.log(inputToArray(testString).reduce(reducer, [[]]));
```

Comment: Don't know, if this changes anything. But each line of the input example is a single user input. So The user will use the first line, the second line or the third line string. Not everything together. Maybe this makes it a bit easier.

Comment: Ah, i see - also i forgot to shorten to initials

Comment: What do you think about solution of revo (just using multiple replaces)?

Comment: Looks good, RegExp is very performant - if it works for your real data i would go with that

Comment: Off the record - i made http://jsfiddle.net/frd6putx/10/ for your previous question - am somehow still there with my thoughts :D

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach. I tried to keep it short but complexity was surprisingly high to get the edge cases.

- First I'm formatting the input, to replace `&` for `,`, and removing `.`.
- Then, I'm splitting the input by `\n`, then `,` and finally  (spaces).
- Next I'm processing the chunks. On each new segment (delimited by `,`), I process the previous segment. I do this because I need to be sure that the current segment isn't an initial. If that's the case, I do my best to skip that inital-only segment and process the previous one. The previous one will have the correct initial and surname, as I have all the information I neeed.
- I get the initial on the segment if there's one. This will be used on the start of the next segment to process the current one.
- After finishing each line, I process again the last segment, as it wont be called otherwise.

I understand the complexity is high without using regexp, and probably would have been better to use a state machine to parse the input instead.

```js
const isInitial = s => [...s].every(c => c === c.toUpperCase());
const generateInitial = arr => arr.reduce((a, c, i) => a + (i < arr.length - 1 ? c[0].toUpperCase() : ''), '');
const formatSegment = (words, initial) => {
  if (!initial) {
    initial = generateInitial(words);
  }
  const surname = words[words.length - 1];
  return {initial, surname};
}

const doDisplay = x => x.map(x => x.surname + ' ' + x.initial).join(', ');

const doProcess = _ => {
  const formatted = input.value.replace(/\./g, '').replace(/&/g, ',');
  const chunks = formatted.split('\n').map(x => x.split(',').map(x => x.trim().split(' ')));
  const peoples = [];
  chunks.forEach(line => {
    let lastSegment = null;
    let lastInitial = null;
    let lastInitialOnly = false;
    line.forEach(segment => {
      if (lastSegment) {
        // if segment only contains an initial, it's the initial corresponding
        // to the previous segment
        const initialOnly = segment.length === 1 && isInitial(segment[0]);
        if (initialOnly) {
          lastInitial = segment[0];
        }
        // avoid processing last segments that were only initials
        // this prevents adding a segment twice
        if (!lastInitialOnly) {
          // if segment isn't an initial, we need to generate an initial
          // for the previous segment, if it doesn't already have one
          const people = formatSegment(lastSegment, lastInitial);
          peoples.push(people);
        }
        lastInitialOnly = initialOnly;
        
        // Skip initial only segments
        if (initialOnly) {
          return;
        }
      }
      lastInitial = null;
      
      // Remove the initial from the words
      // to avoid getting the initial calculated for the initial
      segment = segment.filter(word => {
        if (isInitial(word)) {
          lastInitial = word;
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      });
      lastSegment = segment;
    });
    
    // Process last segment
    if (!lastInitialOnly) {
      const people = formatSegment(lastSegment, lastInitial);
      peoples.push(people);
    }
  });
  return peoples;
}
process.addEventListener('click', _ => {
  const peoples = doProcess();
  const display = doDisplay(peoples);
  output.value = display;
});
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.row > * {
  flex: 1 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <h3>Input</h3>
  <h3>Output</h3>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <textarea id="input" rows="10">Guilcher, G.M., Harvey, M. & Hand, J.P.
Ri Liesner, Peter Tom Collins, Michael Richards
Manco-Johnson M, Santagostino E, Ljung R.
Jordan M, Michael Jackson & Willis B.</textarea>
  <textarea id="output" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
<button id="process" style="display: block;">Process</button>
```